# subset a matrix using the rownames mapping and a user-defined function

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, data.table, apply

I have a matrix and would like to subset it using mapping and function.

Example: Randomly populated matrix using `runif` and `set.seed` for reproducibility.

```
set.seed(1)
exp.mat <- matrix(runif(9*6, 5.0, 10), nrow = 9, ncol = 6)
rownames(exp.mat) <- c('a','b1','b2','b3','c','d1','d2','e1','e2')
colnames(exp.mat) <- c('s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6')

exp.mat
         s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6
a  5.353395 6.661973 6.733417 8.562573 6.198147 8.024666
b1 5.497331 8.254352 6.668875 6.999972 5.294672 8.273620
b2 6.581359 6.290084 7.381756 6.626761 8.211441 6.765986
b3 7.593171 7.392726 9.460992 8.785436 9.381346 6.351301
c  8.310025 8.831553 9.321697 6.013461 8.894573 9.963420
d1 7.034151 5.421235 6.949948 8.555606 8.986544 8.167466
d2 9.564380 9.376607 8.886603 5.608460 7.276372 6.066041
e1 6.468017 6.695365 9.803090 6.227443 7.050420 5.646862
e2 7.295329 9.197202 7.173297 5.716522 9.054351 7.390590
```

Mappings with column `rown` containing `rownames` of original matrix, column `map` containing corresponding mapping.

```
maps <- data.frame(rown=c('a','b1','b2','b3','c','d1','d2','e1','e1','e1'), 
                   map =c('a','b','b','b','c','d','d','e','f','g'))
maps

   rown map
 1    a   a
 2   b1   b
 3   b2   b
 4   b3   b
 5    c   c
 6   d1   d
 7   d2   d
 8   e1   e
 9   e1   f
10   e1   g
```

Function, `mean` is considered here for the selection of rows when there are more mappings(case 2).

```
apply(exp.mat, 1, mean)
       a       b1       b2       b3        c       d1       d2       e1       e2 
6.922362 6.831470 6.976231 8.160829 8.555789 7.519158 7.796410 6.981866 7.637882
```

Based on the mappings,

1. if there is only one value in `rown` mapping to `map` then it should
   directly copy entire row. eg: `a`,`c` have only one mapping.
2. if there are more than one value in `rown` mapping to `map` then it
   should copy the entire row which has the highest value from the      resultant    function above. eg: `b1`, `b2`, `b3` maps to `b`; `b3` has highest `mean`. So, it has to chose `b3` and likewise `d2`.
3. if there is a value in `rown` mapping to more than one value in
   `map`    then it should discard those rows. eg: `e1` has more than one mapping value `e`,`f`.
4. if there is no mapping, then discard the row. eg: `e2` has no corresponding mapping.

Expected output: subsetted matrix

```
> exp.mat.trans
        s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6
a 5.353395 6.661973 6.733417 8.562573 6.198147 8.024666
b 7.593171 7.392726 9.460992 8.785436 9.381346 6.351301
c 8.310025 8.831553 9.321697 6.013461 8.894573 9.963420
d 9.564380 9.376607 8.886603 5.608460 7.276372 6.066041
```

Please advise, how to achieve this in an efficient manner?

I have achieved this eyeballing and the code below

```
exp.mat.trans <- exp.mat[c(1,4,5,7),]
rownames(exp.mat.trans) <- c('a','b','c','d')
```

It might be useful to identify just the indices as there is no transformation of the values?

```
# Index Subsetting
ind <- c(1,4,5,7)
exp.mat.trans2 <- exp.mat[ind,]
rownames(exp.mat.trans2) <- maps[ind, 'map']
```

`exp.mat.trans` and `exp.mat.trans2` are same !

## edit

The `map` and `exp.mat` might not be same always !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an efficient solution I think it would be better to use data.tables for the mapping. Your input matrix is something different if I run it. I found the following solution for the problem:

```
set.seed(1)
exp.mat <- matrix(runif(9*6, 5.0, 10), nrow = 9, ncol = 6)
rownames(exp.mat) <- c('a','b1','b2','b3','c','d1','d2','e1','e2')
colnames(exp.mat) <- c('s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6')
> exp.mat
         s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6
a  6.327543 5.308931 6.900176 6.911940 8.971199 8.946781
b1 6.860619 6.029873 8.887226 9.348454 5.539718 5.116656
b2 7.864267 5.882784 9.673526 6.701745 8.618555 7.386150
b3 9.541039 8.435114 6.060713 7.410401 7.056372 8.661569
c  6.008410 6.920519 8.258369 7.997829 9.104731 8.463658
d1 9.491948 8.849207 5.627775 7.467707 8.235301 7.388098
d2 9.723376 7.488496 6.336103 5.931088 8.914664 9.306047
e1 8.303989 8.588093 6.930570 9.136867 7.765182 7.190486
e2 8.145570 9.959530 5.066952 8.342334 7.648598 6.223986
maps <- data.table(rown=c('a','b1','b2','b3','c','d1','d2','e1','e1'), 
                   map =c('a','b','b','b','c','d','d','e','f'))
#RULE 2 calculate mean of each row
maps[, value := rowMeans(exp.mat)[rown]]
# aggregate such that we know which mapping should be made (RULE 2)
maps <- maps[, rown[which.max(value)], by = map]
# Delete if more mappings are made first find the number of mappings (RULE 3)
number_map <- maps[,.N, by = V1]
setkey(maps, "V1")
# Delete if more than one time a mapping is found
maps <- maps[number_map[N < 2, V1]] 
# Now subset the matrix
exp.mat.sub <- exp.mat[maps$V1[maps$V1 %in% rownames(exp.mat)],]
rownames(exp.mat.sub) <- maps[match(maps$V1, rownames(exp.mat.sub))]$map
exp.mat.sub
         s1       s2       s3       s4       s5       s6
a  6.327543 5.308931 6.900176 6.911940 8.971199 8.946781
b  9.541039 8.435114 6.060713 7.410401 7.056372 8.661569
c  6.008410 6.920519 8.258369 7.997829 9.104731 8.463658
d  9.723376 7.488496 6.336103 5.931088 8.914664 9.306047
```

Comment: `7.564495` has been assigned to the last row when `maps[, value := rowMeans(exp.mat)]` has been executed. But the value was supposed to be for `e2`. However it doesn't matter as the `e2` value is not there. 

Also, this approach doesn't work if the `mapping` object is not having the same rows as `original matrix`

Comment: You are right, I try to fix this problem by sorting the row means based on the  rown column. Does this work for you?

Comment: @tobias-bekker: It works with this example case and I do not foresee any issues. I will implement the same to my original problem and let you know in case of issues. Thanks !

Comment: It didn't work when few of values in `maps$rown`  not present in `row.names(exp.mat)`.. Should all values in `row.names(exp.mat)` be present in `maps$rown` ??